# Get new identity in Tor from Ruby script

Tags: ruby, tor

```
require 'net/telnet'

localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "localhost", "Port" => "9151", "Timeout" => 10, "Prompt" => /250 OK\n/)
localhost.cmd('AUTHENTICATE hi') { |c| print c; throw "Cannot authenticate to Tor" if c != "250 OK\n" }
localhost.cmd('signal NEWNYM') { |c| print c; throw "Cannot switch Tor to new route" if c != "250 OK\n" }
localhost.close
```

I'm trying to get new identity in running Tor using ruby script, code is taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882744/3192470.

My **port** is `9151` because I use *Tor-Bundle*.
To get a **password** hash, I wrote `tor --hash-password hi` in the terminal, which returned `16:970D11D59DCAC06E6075BED460511460C1EFD9CECDBB3C96A59298422A` to me.
I have this line `HashedControlPassword 16:970D11D59DCAC06E6075BED460511460C1EFD9CECDBB3C96A59298422A` in my *torrc* file accordingly.

When I run my Ruby script, I get `uncaught throw "Cannot authenticate to Tor"` exception thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your password in double quotes:

```
localhost.cmd('AUTHENTICATE "hi"') { |c| print c; throw "Cannot authenticate to Tor" if c != "250 OK\n" }
```

That is, the password is that you hashed with `tor --hash-password hi`, but put in double quotes.